# CKFinder (.NET Version). Configuring as an isolated application

Tags: .net, iis, ckeditor, ckfinder

First time/long time.

This question is for people who have installed CKFinder on Windows. As you know, it comes with it's own web.config, app_code, and bin.

We have a large Web application (.NET based).  We have added CKEditor but now we want to add CKFinder. We downloaded CKFinder and installed it and it is appearing in the image icon.  But it is conflicting with the web.config file in the root and throwing thiserror.

"The code subdirectory '/ckfinder/App_Code/WidgetFolder/' does not exist."

I have set CKFinder up to run as an Application per the instructions.  It sounds like it should run as it's own beast.  We really do not want to move all the DLLs in to our bin (as many are duplicates) and we also do not want to modify the web.config file in the root unless we have to.

So how do we get CKFinder to run by itself without interfering with the web.config file in the rootnor the DLLs in the bin?  In other words, how do we make it it's own stand-alone application within the Website?

Comment: By the way, we do have code sub-directories in the root web.config.  That is what it is conflicting with. But I am hoping we can just ignore the web.config
 in the root altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to integrate CKFinder in existing application is adding it as NuGet dependency. Please have a look at: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html#integration_existing_application

This will automatically merge all the required entries to application's `web.config`.

> So how do we get CKFinder to run by itself without interfering with the web.config file in the rootnor the DLLs in the bin? In other words, how do we make it it's own stand-alone application within the Website?

If you *really* want to use CKFinder as a separate application, then you can simply use the application provided in the ZIP package and setup it as described [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_installation_zip).